# Attach all files in a folder to an email

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a ConsoleApplication attach all files in a folder to an email and send it. I know how to do it with a single attachment, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to attach all items in a folder.

**Current code:**

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage("from", "to")

        Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        client.Port = 25
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        client.Host = ""
        mail.Subject = "" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        mail.Body = "Test"

        Dim file As System.Net.Mail.Attachment
        file = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment("Path to single file")


        mail.Attachments.Add(file)


        client.Send(mail)

        Return
    Catch [error] As Exception

        MsgBox("error")

        Return
    End Try

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I tried the below code that I found on another post, but it just errors out (and using the ConsoleApplication, I am not sure how to view the exact error its giving)

```
 For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.FileLoc1)
            Dim Attach As New Net.Mail.Attachment(filePath)
            mail.Attachments.Add(Attach)
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working!

```
 Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim mail As New MailMessage("from", "too")

        Dim client As New SmtpClient()
        client.Port = 25
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        client.Host = ""
        mail.Subject = "" + DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString()
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        mail.Body = "Test"


        For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.FileLoc1)
            Dim Attach As New Net.Mail.Attachment(filePath)
            mail.Attachments.Add(Attach)
        Next


        client.Send(mail)

        Return
    Catch [error] As Exception

        MsgBox("error")

        Return
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: @DavidWilson Ya I was using the right code the whole time, I just had the damn variables messed up! :)